# Price of Reading Data from AWS S3 to a local PySpark dataframe

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, price

I'd like to access my S3 data from a local python script by using PySpark. I am not sure if this is a case of "Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To Internet" and I am going to be charged as stated [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, *yes* :) 
Your data are traversing the Internet from S3 to your local machine, so this is a "**Data transfer OUT**"

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/overview-of-data-transfer-costs-for-common-architectures/